# aside in XeLaTeX can't break line automatically

Tags: xetex, line-breaking

I downloaded a resume template and try to modify it. However, when I modify the email address on the left aside. Since my email address is much longer than the previous mail address within the file. So the email address in the generated pdf just stretched to the main content. How to let LaTeX automatically detect line break within the aside panel so I don't need to adjust it by my own? Thank you very much！

Code:

```
\documentclass[]{friggeri-cv}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}
\header{Songlin}{Yang}
       {social network analyst}


% In the aside, each new line forces a line break
\begin{aside}
  \section{about}
    2925 Dufferin Street
    North York
    Ontario
    ~
    \href{mailto:songlin.yang@mail.utoronto.ca}{songlin.yang@mail.utoronto.ca}
    ~
  \section{languages}
    English
    Chinese
  \section{programming}
    {\color{red} $\varheartsuit$} JavaScript
    (ES5, node.js)
    Python, C, OCaml
    CSS3 \& HTML5
\end{aside}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Why detect automatically? Just break it (wherever you like): `\href{mailto:songlin.yang@mail.utoronto.ca}{songlin.yang@\\mail.utoronto.ca}` (Note: it will probably look better if you use the `colorlinks` option.)

Comment: But if this happens often, manual line breaking will be inconvenient and even affect the symmetry

Comment: Well, without an actual file to test, I can't tell how often it will happen. The snippet you provide suggests that it is using something like `\obeylines`, so you already *are* manually breaking your lines. The email address is different because it is one, continuous series of letters, etc. How many other words are going to be about 20+ characters long?

Comment: Oh, just tested, \\ doesn't affect the symmetry at all. The builder started to recognize the line width of the aside panel again if the length of words is shorter than the total width of the panel.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean -- is that good or bad?  Another idea: do `\href{mailto:songlin.yang@mail.utoronto.ca}{songlin.yang@}` and on the next line: `\href{mailto:songlin.yang@mail.utoronto.ca}{mail.utoronto.ca}`.  (Not automatic, I know....)

Comment: BTW: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>`friggeri-cv.cls` downloaded at http://www.latextemplates.com/template/friggeri-resume-cv.</sub>

To have a break in your email address, you can simply add a space in it:

```
\href{mailto:songlin.yang@mail.utoronto.ca}{songlin.yang@ mail.utoronto.ca}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{friggeri-cv}

\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}
\header{Songlin}{Yang}
       {social network analyst}


% In the aside, each new line forces a line break
\begin{aside}
  \section{about}
    2925 Dufferin Street
    North York
    Ontario
    ~
    \href{mailto:songlin.yang@mail.utoronto.ca}{songlin.yang@ mail.utoronto.ca}
    ~
  \section{languages}
    English
    Chinese
  \section{programming}
    {\color{red} $\varheartsuit$} JavaScript
    (ES5, node.js)
    Python, C, OCaml
    CSS3 \& HTML5
\end{aside}
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Otherwise, you can make more room for the `aside` environment, patching this environment.

That is, add the following lines in your preamble:

```
\patchcmd{\aside}
  {\begin{textblock}{3.6}(1.5, 4.33)}
  {\begin{textblock}{5.3}(0, 4.33)}
  {}{}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{friggeri-cv}

\patchcmd{\aside}
  {\begin{textblock}{3.6}(1.5, 4.33)}
  {\begin{textblock}{5.3}(0, 4.33)}
  {}{}

\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}
\header{Songlin}{Yang}
       {social network analyst}


% In the aside, each new line forces a line break
\begin{aside}
  \section{about}
    2925 Dufferin Street
    North York
    Ontario
    ~
    \href{mailto:songlin.yang@mail.utoronto.ca}{songlin.yang@mail.utoronto.ca}
    ~
  \section{languages}
    English
    Chinese
  \section{programming}
    {\color{red} $\varheartsuit$} JavaScript
    (ES5, node.js)
    Python, C, OCaml
    CSS3 \& HTML5
\end{aside}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: @PuZhao You're welcome. Remember that you can accept the answer to mark the question as solved. See [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)